# Access to the current script tag without id

Tags: html

I wanted to write a small script which will delete itself once executed (for memory).

And for that, I was adding an ID.

Is there a way to access to the script element where the code is from the code itself without using IDs?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The amount of RAM saved is absolutely minuscule.

Comment: @Blender For my conscience :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it based on the index it is (i.e. is it the 3rd script tag, 2nd, etc)

```
var scriptNum = 0;
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[scriptNum];
```

Comment: Very good! And I can test if the 5 first letters of `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[i];` are the same as the 5 of the current script (instead of telling "the first script tag").

Comment: @Mageek - Because a script runs as soon as it is added to the DOM, if the script element is added by the HTML parser (as opposed to being added by another piece of javascript), it will always initially be the **last** script element in the DOM. This means that you don't need to know how many other script elements precede it.